# jQuery: Binding Scroll Event to dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface, scroll

I've been developing an application recently which uses the vertical scroll bar extensively for its UI. I've been using jQuery to do a lot of my work but recently I've hit a bit of a speed bump.

All of my content is being loaded in dynamically, including the div which will have the scroll bar. Binding .scroll to that specific div does not do anything. I've tried multiple approaches through closure functions, using .on and .live but none seem to work.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score -2):

Bind it to the document instead:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '#divId', function() { /* ... code ... */ });
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to have worked, I've also tried using .live with that method.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, surely someone must know the answer??

Comment: @SimonSturgess hmm [**It appears the scroll event doesn't bubble**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-scroll) You can either bind directly to the element when it's loaded, or bind the function on the first mousein or poll or...